# Why reject as too minor?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

The following edit has been rejected as too minor

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32981

Why?

If you read the sentence it's obvious that the edit needs to be made, if you read the entire post it's obvious that only one edit needs to be made to it.

Answer (score 11):

For me, being no native speaker, the sentence was difficult to understand before the edit. Allowing users to fix grammar mistakes is a win, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The too minor reason exists because all edits by low rep users have to be reviewed by another user, therefore we try to maximize the benefit of their effort by encouraging only substantial edits. In this case your edit made the question grammatically correct, but the meaning was still clear in the incorrect version, so little was gained. Somewhat more informally the question you edited is a bit older and hasn't had any activity in a while, editing old settled questions with minor typos hurts newer questions by pushing them off the page faster, so a general rule of thumb is to only edit older questions when the edit would be a marked improvement rather than a minor grammatical or spelling error.

Comment: *"editing old settled questions with minor typos hurts newer questions"* That's the real issue then, I don't think there should be any barriers to improving the content on the site, no matter how small the improvement or how old the content.

Comment: @MattDavey - you have a kindred spirit with Anna Lear.  http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/2521/53019.  I think some of us (myself included) had forgotten the qualifier of "too many edits at one time".  It's good to edit old questions and clean them up; we just need to keep the rate under control so we don't flood the front page.